# Is $\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3$ symplectic?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

My first idea was to argue that if there was a symplectic form $\omega$, then we would have $[\omega\wedge\omega]=[0]$ (in deRham cohomology), since $H_{dR}^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{S^3})=0$, which is absurd.

But I've noticed this is wrong, since the argument "$\omega\in\Omega^2(M)$ symplectic $\Rightarrow H_{dR}^2(M)\neq 0$" is valid only if $M$ is compact, which is not the case for $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3$.

Now I don't really know what to do.

Is there some generic strategy for this kind of problem?

Comment: **HINT**: What's the standard example of symplectic manifolds?

Comment: @TedShifrin $\mathbb{R}^n$ with standard symplectic form? I'm not following

Comment: No, does the phrase *cotangent bundle* ring a bell?

Comment: right before Uldreth posted his answer, I've read that $\mathbb{S}^3$ is parallelizable, so $\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\simeq T^*\mathbb{S}^3$, which symplectic. That's it, right?

Comment: I wish there was simpler way, since $\mathbb{S}^3$ being parallelizable is clearly "privileged" information. I would never have guessed myself

Comment: Not very privileged. Lie groups always have trivial (co)tangent bundle.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am shooting wildly here, but $S^3$ is parallelizable (it is a principal homogenous space for $\text{SU}(2)$), hence its tangent (and thus, cotangent) bundle is trivial and is diffeomorphic to $S^3\times\mathbb R^3$.

Cotangent bundles carry a natural symplectic form, hence $S^3\times\mathbb R^3$ admits symplectic forms.

Comment: I haven't seen the phrase "principal homogeneous space" before - what does it mean?  (I know principal bundles and I know homogeneous spaces.  I've just never seen the two terms used in tandem like that.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito It is the group equivalent of an affine space, eg. a group whose identity element you forget. I have used the term because if I consider $S^3$ as the subset $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$ in $\mathbb R^4$, then there is no preferred choice of the identity element. The fibres of principal bundles are principal homogenous spaces in this sense, since local trivializations identify the fibres with $G$, but even the identitiy elements in each fibres are trivialization-dependent.

Comment: Makes sense!  I have also heard the phrase $G$-torsor for what you describe.

Comment: @JasonDeVito A cursory glance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space tells me this is indeed the case, and "torsor" is a synonym for what I've called a principal homogenous space.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't even think of googling the phrase.  Now I feel like I've really wasted your time.  Anyway, thanks!